# How to scan Negative barcodes with Google ML Kit?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

How to scan Google ML Kit Data Matrix negative color barcode.
I can read white-on-black barcodes. But I can't read black-on-white barcodes.
I need to preprocess but I couldn't.
I am using Google ML Kit with Android Java.

Comment: I'm afraid Google ML Kit doesn't support inverted colored barcode,  since our current implementation is based on ZXing, and ZXing doesn't support inverted colored barcode. There are some discussions online on how to preprocess the image before passing it to the decoder, you can refer to their solutions for these inverted barcodes.

Comment: Yes, I have reviewed previous threads. The image requires preprocessing. Windows CE terminal devices from 15 years ago can read reverse barcodes.
I hope one day it will be supported by MLKit.